# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'AngularSignaturePadModule' was called

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular Signature Pad. There is some issue with this line:

```
AngularSignaturePadModule.forRoot(),
```

> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Function calls
>   are not supported in decorators but 'AngularSignaturePadModule' was
>   called.

I don't know what to pass in `.forRoot()`. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Check how you import the code

For example:
This was bad

```
import { SampleService } from './services'
```

This is good

```
import { SampleService } from './services/sample.service'
```

Because you always have to specify the file name if you are not export in the index.ts file like this

```
export * from './services/sample.service'
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to how exactly is this relevant in the context of the question?

Comment: `@Tony Ngo Actually AngularSignaturePadModule.forRoot() is inherited from ModuleWithProviders i.e.

export declare class AngularSignaturePadModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders;
}

Now, here is the issue, the forRoot() need module and providers i.e

export interface ModuleWithProviders {
    ngModule: Type<any>;
    providers?: Provider[];
}`